# PHP. Cannot append to the file

Tags: php, apache, fwrite, php-5.5

Well, I have a problem. On my local LAMP (14.04 LTS 32 bit) all works as magic. Remote server also is Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit).
On the production my program successfully rewrites file:

```
$myfileresult = fopen('taranko.csv','w+');
echo fwrite($myfileresult,"");
fclose($myfileresult);
```

but after it my script failed to append any information.

```
$myfileresult = fopen('download.csv','a');
                fwrite($myfileresult, $ids.";".$imageLinkAlt.";".$itemNameAlt.";".$features.";".$mods[$x].";".$prices[$x].";".$stockQty[$x].PHP_EOL);
                fclose($myfileresult);
```

I have

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in my script, but there are no errors or warnings in PHP echo, indeed.
I tried to append this string:
"1701-1;http://taranko-shop.ru/.."
So, I used strace, this is what I found:

```
open("/home/ci65797/web/mydomain.com/public_html/download.csv", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 24
2056  fstat(24, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=160740, ...}) = 0
2056  lseek(24, 0, SEEK_CUR)            = 0
2056  lseek(24, 0, SEEK_CUR)            = 0
2056  write(24, "1701-1;http://taranko-shop.ru/wa"..., 377) = 377
2056  close(24)
```

So, next to the latest string contains my string, which I tried to append.
My all directories are 755, the file is 644.
What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You're appending empty string.

Comment: Not quite. I tried to append this: 1701-1;http://taranko-shop.ru/wa Write, the second parameter contains the string I tried to append. @u_mulder

Comment: @Areso, then _show us that in your question_! How are we supposed to know what your code _actually_ does if you change it when asking here?

Comment: @Chris I don't change the code. I demonstrated working part, which as described, rewrites file (it works). I asking about the part which is not written down, though this part is in strace.

Comment: "I asking about the part which is not written down"—that's exactly the problem. We can't help you with code we can't see. strace doesn't count. Thank you for editing your question.

Comment: Why are the file names in the two calls to `fopen()` different? I suspect that's your problem: your data is getting written, just not to the file you expect.

Comment: Probably because I was too tired and forgot to rename the file in this part of the code... Now it works, thank you a lot. And yes, I checked it, it really wrote the output to download.csv, though I didn't create it nor upload it when uploaded my script to the production server. The script works better than me. Can you repeat your comment (2 or 3) as an answer, so, I can flag it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Chris suggests, my script just wrote to another file. It happened because I renamed file in the first part of my script and don't renamed in the second.